# How to have multiple sets of scatter markers with different colormaps in Plotly Express?

Tags: python, plotly, colormap

I'm trying to make a plot with two (or more) sets of points that
that are plotted according to different colormaps.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458220/two-or-three-colorbars-for-one-plot-in-plotly), however when I try to modify the example answer that used Express, I still only get one colormap for all points, and only one colorbar instead of two.

The is following minimum (non-)working example. I want to get one cluster of points shown with the 'inferno' colormap , and another set of points plotted using 'viridis' color map, and a colorbar for each:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

npoints = 100
data1 = np.random.rand(npoints,4)
columns = ['x','y','z','c']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columns)
fig = px.scatter_3d(df1, x='x', y='y', z='z', color='c',
                    color_continuous_scale='inferno')
fig.update_coloraxes(colorscale="inferno")
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.x = 1.1 # move 1st colorbar to make room for 2nd?

data2 = 0.5*np.random.rand(npoints,4)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns)
fig2 = px.scatter_3d(df2, x='x', y='y', z='z', color='c',
                     color_continuous_scale='viridis')
fig2.update_coloraxes(colorscale="viridis")

fig.add_traces(list(fig2.select_traces()))  # add fig2 to fig

fig.show()
```

But instead all points have the same 'inferno' map and there's only one colorbar:

[image: resulting image only has one colormap]

Can someone assist in fixing this?

(I don't understand why my use case is different from the similar question -- I tried similar code but it doesn't work.  If my question were simply a "duplicate" then I wouldn't need to ask this.)

**EDIT**: One other potential duplicate is here: [Plotly: How to use two color scales in a single plotly map figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504743/plotly-how-to-use-two-color-scales-in-a-single-plotly-map-figure), however, trying to implement what I see there, i.e. similarly trying to move the colorbar layout, copying coloraxes, using `fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])`,... still results in only one colormap for my case.

**EDIT 2**: User error. Forgot to include the `fig['data'][1]...` info from code mentioned in EDIT 1. With that, it works as expected. My question is therefore a dupe.  Closing.